# Visual Studio 2019 starts Docker-compose in Edge Browser with Bing Search

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, docker-compose

my Visual Studio 2019 starts the Docker-compose file and open the Edge Browser to show the swagger page. But it always send a search request to bing with the following text: "--disable-quic --edge-redirect=Windows.Protocol https://localhost:50746/swagger"

Did anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just restart my computer and it works :)